# In Spring, how do I create a POJO with a default value from configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I am using the Spring framework to with a properties file that has the key:

```
empty.value = -
```

I would like to be able to create a POJO that would have that empty value as its default value for the default constructor of the POJO. Something like this:

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;

    public Dog(){
    }

    public Dog(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So that if `Dog d = new Dog()` is called, `d.name` will be `-` from the `empty.value` key.

Autowiring the `name` variable will just be `null` because Spring isn't aware of the POJO as well as using `@Value("${empty.value}")`.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

**Edit**: To clarify, there are meant to be many `Dog`s throughout the system and I need to be able to initialize them on request.

**Edit 2**: Consider the following use case- I have an interface containing a method:

```
Dog transform(List<String> animals);
```

I would like to be able to know that whatever `Dog` is returned from the transform method has either `-` (configurable) as a `name` or a different value passed in to the constructor when created (or setter, later). I would like to ensure that for whatever `transform` does in any implementation, even if it fails, I will have a valid `Dog` with a `name` as mentioned.

Comment: Generally, have your creator code pass the value in. Can you provide more detail about your use case?

Comment: Provided more info in Edit 2.

Comment: @RELnemtzov does mi last update answers your question? if not, please clarify or put example on whats supposed to do the transform method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Spring framework, you have to create all your Spring beans using also Spring. For example:

```
Dog d = (Dog)context.getBean("dog");
```

Doing `Dog d = new Dog()` is a valid instance, but that way it's not processed by Spring.

**Update about the Edit 2**

If you want to ensure you always have a valid dog instance when calling the `transform` method, you can use a `try catch` block in the caller code. For example:

```
// caller class
Dog dog = null;
try{
   dog = yourInterface.transform(animals);
   if (dog == null || !validName(dog.name)){
       throw new RuntimeException("Not a valid dog/name");   
   }
}catch(Exception ex){
   dog = (Dog)context.getBean("dog");
}
```

Comment: correct, Dog d = new Dog() lives in the heap . Dog d = (Dog)context.getBean("dog"); lives in the spring container.